# How can one securely log users in automatically after previous Facebook authentication?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, cookies, facebook-graph-api

Users are complaining they have to login too frequently.  If authentication is entirely built on Facebook OAuth, how can a user be logged in automatically the next time they visit the page?

**Example user flow:**

1. User clicks "Login with Facebook"
2. User authenticates with Facebook and is redirected back to site
3. User is confirmed and logged in.
4. User closes window on site (but not browser)
5. User visits a few hours later and has to re-auth to Facebook to gain access again *(users complain about this)*

**Ideal User Flow**

- Users are logged in automatically for each visit
- **Exception:** If a user clicks "logout", it should require re-auth next time they visit.

How can one do this safely and securely?

**Notes:**

- No username or password is ever stored locally, only a local user id and their associated Facebook user id.
- "Offline Access" is already included/granted in the OAuth 2.0 request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the JS-SDK [`FB.getLoginStatus()` method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
    // reload page or use ajax to update content of page
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than instructing the users to check the "keep me logged on to Facebook" checkbox, the simplest way is to set a cookie of your own which contains identifying information. Naturally there is a security concern here regarding multiple users on one computer, but it's pretty common practice and most users/sites find it perfectly acceptable.

The only thing you have to be really careful about is that your cookie value uniquely identifies the user and cannot be counterfeited by a different user. Since you are using offline_permission tokens, you could even use that as a part of a cookie value since it is already unique to each user and "unguessable" by other users. Other options would be an md5 composed of the userid plus some secret string, or even a completely random string that is stored in your db and linked to the local userid.

When the user explicitly logs off, you just clear the cookie and the user will have to authenticate again the next time around.

And just to be clear, I am interpreting your question as regarding authentication (identification) only, not authorization (permissions), since you mentioned having offline_access already granted.