# How to automatically authenticate users with their facebook accounts, providing they have connected to my website before

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

UPDATE: It seems that this is [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827287/how-can-one-securely-log-users-in-automatically-after-previous-facebook-authenti?rq=1). Sorry for not searching thoroughly before posting.

I'm building a website using PHP that allows users to sign in via their Facebook accounts. Everything works fine except that users always have to click a button to sign back in. I notice that some websites like [goodreads.com](http://goodreads.com) can automatically detect my Facebook account, even after I have deleted all its cookies. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Some of them use an embedded iframe that sends the user to Facebook then back to your site and the code in this iframe communicates with the parent window telling it which user you are

but the return url for the Facebook should be in the same domain as your website

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know any examples or reference on Facebook?